# magento: database synchronization between production, staging & development

Tags: database, magento, synchronization, production

I've been reading up today on database synchronization in Magento.

One thing I am currently struggling with is what needs to be synced during development and during uploads to production. Now assuming that a batch of changes will consist of changes to the DB and code alike, below would be my understanding of a model workflow (I do not currently use a '**stage**' server so that is bypassed in this example):

1. Sync **dev** DB from **production** DB
2. Checkout working copy of code to dev machine
3. Make changes and test them on **dev** server
4. Accept changes and commit them to svn repository
5. Touch Maintenance.flag on production server and prepare for upgrades *(this altogether eliminates sync issues from users interacting with live data that is about to change right?)*
6. Merge branches to trunk and deploy repository to production server
7. Sync **dev** DB back to **production** DB and test changes

So items # 1 & 7 I don't fully understand when working with Magento:

- What needs to be synced and what doesn't?

  - It seems ridiculous to sync order and customer info to me so I wouldn't do it.
  - I would want product schema and data synced though obviously, and any admin changes, module changes, etc. How to handle that?
- What about HOW to sync? (MySql dumps, import/export, etc)

  - Currently I'm using Navicat 10 Premium which has structure and data sync features (I haven't experimented yet but they look like a huge help)

So I don't necessarily need specifics here (but they would help). More or less I want to know what works for you and how happy you are with that system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use phpunit to build a dev db.  I wrote a [short script](https://github.com/elcash/mageunit-satellite/blob/master/generate_flat_xml.php) which dumps xml data from the live database and I used it table-by-table, munging anything sensitive and deleting what I didn't need.  The schema for my dev database never changes and never gets rebuilt.  Only the data gets dropped and recreated each phpunit run.

May not be the right solution for everyone because it's never going to be good for syncing dev up to stage/production, but I don't need to do that.

The main benefit is how little data I need for the dev db.  It's about 12000 lines of xml, and handles populating maybe 30 different tables.  Some small core tables persist as I don't write to them and many tables are empty because I do not use them.

The database is a representative sample, and is very small.  Small enough to edit as a text file, and only a few seconds to populate each time I run tests.

Here's what it looks like at the top of each PHPUnit test.  There's good documentation for [PHPUnit](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/index.html) and [DbUnit](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/database.html)

```
<?php
require_once dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'top.php';
require_once "PHPUnit/Extensions/Database/TestCase.php";

class SomeTest extends PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_TestCase 
{
    /**
     * @return PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_DB_IDatabaseConnection
     */
    public function getConnection() {
        $database = MY_DB
        $hostname = MY_HOST
        $user     = MY_USER
        $password = MY_PASS
        $pdo      = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$database", $user, $password);
        return $this->createDefaultDBConnection($pdo, $database);
    }

   /**
    * @return PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_DataSet_IDataSet
    */
    public function getDataSet() {
    return $this->createXMLDataSet(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'Tests/_files/seed.xml');
    }
}
```

So, now you just need a seed file that DbUnit reads from to repopulate your database each time Unit tests are invoked.

Start by copying your complete database twice.  One will be your dev database and the second will be your "pristine" database, that you can use to dump xml data in case you start having key issues.

Then, use something like my xml dumper againt the "prisine" database to get your xml dumps and begin building your seed file.

```
generate_flat_xml.php -tcatalog_product_entity -centity_id,entity_type_id,attribute_set_id,type_id,sku,has_options,required_options -oentity_id >> my_seed_file.xml
```

Edit the seed file to use only what you need.  The small size of the dev db means you can examine differences just by looking at your database versus what's in the text files.  Not to mention it is much faster having less data.

Comment: I'm curious with this method because I agree with you that the dev db doesn't need a lot of data to test with. Mainly products, settings, etc. I've never even heard of phpUnit until this post. I'm curious, if you don't mind, to see more hands-on of how you accomplish this scenario. I just want to keep this simple-stupid and easy to manage especially since I am brand new on versioning and handling a site of this magnitude.

Comment: Awesome, I really appreciate all the help. I will give this a whirl int he next few days after I wrap up a couple things and have some time to spare.

Answer (score 5):

if you are using CE version then:

- ditch svn and use GIT :)
- never sync a database , prepare your database upgrades as extension upgrade files

  1. have 3 sites dev, stage, live
  2. live database is copied over to stage and dev when needed
  3. make all your admin changes from live and just copy the whole database down the line

this way you never have to sync a database + if you do all config changes via extension upgrade scripts you can cold boot your magento to a new database structure wherever you want without loosing data structure

Comment: +1 for using Git. Copy the live database to stage/dev by using a script which does data modifications, e.g. changing the core URL entries, store e-mail addresses and authorization information for third-party payment interfaces. Anonymize/Change customer and order data.

Comment: I personally use fabric scripts to handle that and yes as Matthias explained some sql update scripts are also needed to ensure continuous  and smooth flow between environments.

Comment: Hey if you want me to ditch SVN at least tell me why :). If one of you could show me a script or a sample or point me in the right direction to start one that would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: Question , are you sure its a good idea to make admin changes on live ? what if you a mistake in real time ?

Comment: who gives a f*ck if you are not earning $1mil in real time :) then you just fix your mistakes